# Does unsafe code have any effect on safe code?

Tags: c#, .net, unsafe

As I understand it, marking an method as unsafe will disable some of the CLR checks on that code, but does this have any effect on the rest of the system which is safe, other than the fact that the DLL/EXE can not run in a untrusted environment.

In particular,

1. Are they are any safety checks that will not work on the complete dll because it is marked as unsafe?
2. If a DLL is marked as unsafe, but the methods marked as unsafe are
   not actually called, is this the same as if the DLL is marked as
   safe?
3. Are they any run-time benefits on keeping the unsafe code in a
   separate DLL?

I have the problem with redrawing nested controls on 64-bit windows as detailed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/11/20/controls-won-t-get-resized-once-the-nesting-hierarchy-of-windows-exceeds-a-certain-depth-x64.aspx) and the one the solutions (the one that appears to work) involves unsafe code and I would like to understand the effect that adding this code has to my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is: The `unsafe` keyword does not mean "unsafe", it means "potentially unsafe". The compiler and framework cannot work to make certain that it's safe. It is up to you to make certain that the code cannot perform unsafe reads or writes to memory.

I would strongly encourage you to follow this advice given in the article you linked:

1) Redesign the application to have **less containers** and **reduce the number of nesting levels**.

If you're using containers for the sole purpose of control arrangement, write your own container that can do all the arrangement with one level.

**Updated**

You can modify the code in that article so that it doesn't use pointers (i.e. doesn't require the unsafe keyword). Keep in mind that this will now require marshalling which means extra copying. This is probably a good thing because the original code is passing a WINDOWPOS pointer from the OS to BeginInvoke which does not execute during the same dispatch event that the OS generated the pointer in. In other words, that code was smelly already.

```
internal class MyTabPage : TabPage
{
    private const int WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 70;
    private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 0xB;
    private const int SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;
    private const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
    private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    private const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    extern static int SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    extern static bool SetWindowPos(HandleRef hWnd, HandleRef hWndInsertAfter,
    int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int flags);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private class WINDOWPOS
    {
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public IntPtr hwndInsertAfter;
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public int cx;
        public int cy;
        public int flags;
    };

    private delegate void ResizeChildDelegate(WINDOWPOS wpos);

    private void ResizeChild(WINDOWPOS wpos)
    {
        // verify if it's the right instance of MyPanel if needed
        if ((this.Controls.Count == 1) && (this.Controls[0] is Panel))
        {
            Panel child = this.Controls[0] as Panel;

            // stop window redraw to avoid flicker
            SendMessage(new HandleRef(child, child.Handle), WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0);

            // start a new stack of SetWindowPos calls
            SetWindowPos(new HandleRef(child, child.Handle), new HandleRef(null, IntPtr.Zero),
            0, 0, wpos.cx, wpos.cy, SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);

            // turn window repainting back on 
            SendMessage(new HandleRef(child, child.Handle), WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0);

            // send repaint message to this control and its children
            this.Invalidate(true);
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING)
        {
            WINDOWPOS wpos = new WINDOWPOS();
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, wpos);

            Debug.WriteLine("WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING received by " + this.Name + " flags " + wpos.flags);

            if (((wpos.flags & (SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE)) == (SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE)) &&
            ((wpos.flags & ~(SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE)) == 0))
            {
                if ((wpos.cx != this.Width) || (wpos.cy != this.Height))
                {
                    BeginInvoke(new ResizeChildDelegate(ResizeChild), wpos);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

**Note**: The change in WINDOWPOS from value type to reference type is intentional. Using a reference type reduces the number of copies to just one (the initial marshal)(**).

**Updated Again**
I just noticed that the code originally made the p/invoke declarations public. Never, ever expose p/invoke outside of a class(*). Write managed methods that invoke private p/invoke declarations if your intent is to expose the capabilities provided; which in this case is not true, the p/invoke is strictly internal.

(*) Ok, one exception. You're creating a `NativeMethods`, `UnsafeNativeMethods`, etc. Which is the recommended way to do p/invoke by FxCop.

**Updated**

(**) I was asked (elsewhere) to describe precicely why using a reference type here is better, so I've added that info here. The question I was asked was, "Doesn't this add memory pressure?"

If `WINDOWPOS` was a value type, this would be the sequence of events:

1) Copy from unmanaged to managed memory

```
WINDOWPOS wpos = Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(WINDOWPOS));
```

2) Second copy?

```
BeginInvoke(new ResizeChildDelegate(ResizeChild), wpos);
```

Wait! The signature of `BeginInvoke` is `(Delegate, params object[])`. That means wpos is going to get boxed. So yes, a second copy occurs here: The boxing operation.

`BeginInvoke` will add the delegate and object[] to an invocation list and post a registered window message. When that message is removed from the queue by the message pump, the delegate will be called with the object[] parameters.

3) Unbox and copy for `ResizeChild` call.

At this point you can see that the number of copies isn't even the issue. The fact that it gets converted to a reference type (boxed) means that we are better off making it a reference type to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still hoping to find a method which avoids using unsafe code, but haven't found a reliable way (as yet). Redesigning the application would not be trivial as involves multiple user-controls which are re-used in various places.  However, I think you (and others) are missing the point of the question I was trying (and obviously failing) to ask, which is whether marking a dll as unsafe and marking a method as unsafe has any effect of the rest of the code in the dll or application even if we assume that the actual unsafe code nevers goes wrong.

Comment: @sgmoore: I updated my answer to show how to remove the use of pointers from the code. It doesn't answer the question, but I don't know the details involved in using the /unsafe switch.

Comment: Thanks that appears to work. I will obviously have to do a lot more testing and also try to figure out what it does. For example the consequences on invoking ReSizeChild and not calling base.WndProc(ref m) if ReSizeChild does not do anything.

Comment: @sgmoore: Not calling base.WndProc bypasses whatever code the framework has for dealing with WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING. For Control.WndProc it does nothing but call DefWndProc (unless *this* is an ActiveX control which it is not). Calling DefWndProc would result in size-change-recursion, the very thing that is being avoided.

Comment: Whilst this does actually answer the question I asked, it solves my problem and problem answers the question I should have asked. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, "safe" code is just "potentially safe", since safe code can dllimport, as well as handle or modify IntPtr which is handed to someone else's dllimport. Both of those can cause crashes or memory corruption. Begging the question "what does safe even mean?"

Comment: @DavidJeske Safe, in the context of a .NET application, means: "Verifiable". If the compiler and the run-time can verify that a memory write won't occur to the wrong location or overflow into a wrong location, then the operation is 'safe'.

Comment: @Tergiver - David Jeske already demonstrated why Verifiable does not guarantee that memory writes are valid.

Answer (score 8):

An unsafe code is **capable** of *corrupting the managed heap*. As such, anything that runs in the **same process** can be affected.

This includes all other **libraries** and potentially all other **AppDomains** in the same process.

---

## UPDATE

Here is an example:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/02/09/net-crash-managed-heap-corruption-calling-unmanaged-code.aspx

---

## UPDATE 2

> Is unsafe code that is written
>   diligently bad?

No. There are **tons** of unsafe code in the .NET framework itself. Examples many, but here  is one in the `System.String`:

```
public static unsafe string Copy(string str)
{
    if (str == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("str");
    }
    int length = str.Length;
    string str2 = FastAllocateString(length);
    fixed (char* chRef = &str2.m_firstChar)
    {
        fixed (char* chRef2 = &str.m_firstChar)
        {
            wstrcpyPtrAligned(chRef, chRef2, length);
        }
    }
    return str2;
}
```

Comment: I understand and have to accept the risks involved if there are bugs in the unsafe code, but assuming that the unsafe code works perfectly (or is never executed), is my overall system any less safe.

Comment: Exactly. They made the keyword "unsafe" for a reason.

Comment: @Harry: Indeed, even while MS marketing didn't want the team to call is `unsafe` (http://www.artima.com/intv/choices2.html). Glad they did call it `unsafe`.

Comment: "safe" code is also capable of corrupting the heap, because safe code can dllimport, and hand that entry point invalid pointers, including "new IntPtr(666)".